# django transaction management with class based view

Tags: python, django

I have a class based view and that has method post as follows

```
class Comment(View):

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Comment, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    @method_decorator(transaction.non_atomic_requests)
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        <Some code>
```

In above example transaction.non_atomic_requests does not make post method non atomic, but if I use same decorator for dispatch method then it works? Why?

I am using django 1.9

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use the [`transaction.non_atomic_requests`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/transaction.py#L283) decorator, it sets an attribute `_non_atomic_requests` on the decorated object.

Django then checks for the `_non_atomic_requests` attribute when the view runs.

When Django runs a class based view, it doesn't run the `dispatch` method directly, it runs the view that is returned by the `as_view()` method.

There is code in the `as_view()` method that copies attributes like `_non_atomic_requests` from the `dispatch` method to the view that is returned.

However the `as_view` method does not copy attributes from any other methods like `get` or `post`. When you decorate the `post` method, the `_non_atomic_requests` attribute is not copied to the view, so the decorator does not work.

Therefore, you must apply decorators like `transaction.non_atomic_requests` or `csrf_exempt` to the `dispatch` method.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Alasdair. You have explained it wonderfully. I was missing  as_view() method to take in consideration. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

According to the django documentation:

> To decorate every instance of a class-based view, you need to decorate the class definition itself. To do this you apply the decorator to the dispatch() method of the class.

The dispatch is the first method that handle the request for the view.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class