# Django rest framework non_atomic_requests based on HTTP method

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django Rest Framework and its class-based view, with database connection set to `ATOMIC_REQUESTS=True`.

To optimize the application, I would like to have it so that only PUT and POST requests are under transaction, but not GET.  Since I have ATOMIC_REQUESTS on, the documentation says to use the decorator on the `dispatch()` method in the view.  So this is what I tried:

```py
class MyView(APIView):
    def get():
        print("I am in a transaction:", not transaction.get_autocommit())
        return Response({})

    def post():
        print("I am in a transaction:", not transaction.get_autocommit())
        return Response({})

    def put():
        print("I am in a transaction:", not transaction.get_autocommit())
        return Response({})

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """Override dispatch method and selectively apply non_atomic_requests"""
        if request.method.lower() == "get":
            return self.non_atomic_dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    @transaction.non_atomic_requests
    def non_atomic_dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """Special dispatch method decorated with non_atomic_requests"""
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

This does not work, since the get method still reports itself as under transaction, however, if I switch the decorator to look like this:

```py
    ...
    
    @transaction.non_atomic_requests
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method.lower() == "get":
            return self.non_atomic_dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def non_atomic_dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
        
    ...
```

This works, though obviously it's not what I want.

My questions are:

1. Why does the placement of the decorator matter, if I am merely returning the same thing?
2. How do I make this work the way I want?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44596892/6759844) answer explains this behavior.

Comment: IIRC, the view has access to the incoming request, (via view.request) so you can probably override `non_atomic_requests` to also flag `_non_atomic_requests` based on request method

Comment: Thank you for the link!  That does answer the 1st question I have about behavior.

Comment: In regards to the second comment, I am not sure how that can be done, if I understand the behavior.  Since decorators are evaluated at application start up (when urls.py URLs gets processed and `as_view()` as called, I presume), then the flag `_non_atomic_requests` has already been set even before any request comes in.  How do I change `non_atomic_requests` to get during runtime instead, without messing with internal APIs?

Comment: Ah you may be right. I will try to test this later.